# Truffle compiler version error

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment, contract-debugging, truffle-contract

I keep getting an error that my truffle is currently running version `0.5.16`.
`Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.16, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity >=0.8.4"`

My truffle.js has the following:

```
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: ">=0.8.4",
    },
  }
```

Under `module.exports`.

But I am still getting this error.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: What does `truffle --version` return?

Comment: @Ismael I have the required version installed.